# Is there any difference between these two approaches when using Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I just changed my code to make the code look better. Is there any difference between these two approaches when using Promise? I am just afraid if it will affect the program logic. Thanks a lot.

Code Before changing:

```
function clearTableDemo(tableName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (db) {
            db.executeSql('DELETE FROM '+ tableName, [],
                () => { resolve () },
                err => { reject() }
            );
        } else {
            reject('db no open');
        }
    });
}
```

Code After changing: **(UPDATED)**

```
function clearTableDemo(tableName) {
    if (!db) return Promise.reject('db no open');
    db.executeSql('DELETE FROM '+ tableName, [],
        () => { return Promise.resolve() },
        err => { return Promise.reject(err) }
    );
}
```

Comment: There is a huge difference: The second example does not return a Promise.

Comment: Have you actually tried to use the second example when there is `db` ? :)

Comment: Sorry for mistake of the demo code. What if i rewrote the code with following ?
db.executeSql('DELETE FROM '+ tableName, [], () => { return Promise.resolve() }, err => { return Promise.reject(err) });

Comment: @DickyChan Your updated code looks the same. It doesn't return a promise. Just try it. You'll see the error.

Answer (score 6):

The two functions are completely different, the second example does not return a Promise at all.

What you can do to simplify the function is, for example, the following code:

```
function clearTableDemo(tableName) {
    if (!db) {
        return Promise.reject('db no open');
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.executeSql('DELETE FROM '+ tableName, [], resolve, reject);
    });
}
```